# will a womens attraction for other men in jannah be taken away?

Tags: women, jannah

Assalamualaikum, I read this somewhere, Ibn Katheer said: “ they (the women of Jannah) lower their gaze and avoid looking at men other than their husbands, so they do not think that there is anything in Paradise that is more handsome than their husbands. Does this mean that the innate attraction women have for other men will be taken away from them while men will still  have their attractions for their houris. Does this mean that Women will not be able to ask Allah for men other than the one she marries? I trust in Allah and am aware that he is just with all, but this matter has really troubled me because I was told that man and women will get whatever their hearts will want, for example, if a women wants another male will she not be able to do so since that desire will be taken away from her? I know that bad parts of human will be taken away like jealousy and hatred but since this feeling will remain for men, then it isnt a bad thing. And if it is going to be taken away, what if she doesnt want it to? does she have a choice?.  May Allah forgive me if I have said anything out of turn.
And thank you for answering my question, may Allah kindly reward you.

Comment: The same would, I suppose, apply to a man. He wouldn't find anyone more attractive than his wives. "Houris" will be married to them. They would be wives.